# How to select a particular <g> which has particular text in <text> as its child using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have html as follows

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <rect></rect>
        <text> abc </text>
    </g>

    <g>
        <rect></rect>
        <text> def </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I want to select the g tag which has the child text tag as its value " abc " and should append some other text tags to it, such that the final output will be

```
    <svg>
    <g>
        <rect></rect>
        <text> abc </text>
        <text> extra added abc </text>
    </g>

    <g>
        <rect></rect>
        <text> def </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Target the `g` tag that `has()` the `text` tag, that `contains()` the string `abc`, then append the element to that `g` tag like this.

```
$('g:has(text:contains("abc"))').append($('<text />', {text : ' extra added abc '}));
```

Comment: :Thanks for the reply, but i got an other issue, appending this way, its creating the html code properly (checked with F12 in chrome), but wont show in the chrome (i mean the UI)... Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
  $('g text:contains(abc)').closest('g').append('<text> extra added abc </text>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $('g text:contains(abc)').after('<text> extra added abc </text>');
});
```